# typenamed iterator is not a type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, iterator

I'm writing a templated class, which involves use of iterators. I've found the many questions about how you need to typename an iterator if you're using it with a template, so I'm wondering why it's still not working.

```
#pragma once

#include <iterator>
#include <list>
#include <tuple>

template <class T>
class Quack
{
    private:
        std::list<T> data;
        typename std::list<T>::iterator iter;

    public:
        Quack();

        void insert(T dat);
        std::tuple<T, T> poppop();

    private:
        //error: 'iter' does not name a type
        iter binarySearch(T toFind, std::list<T>::iterator min, std::list<T>::iterator max);
};
```

I also tried `typedef typename std::list<T>::iterator iter;`, but that throws up the error "std::list::iterator is not a type"

So given that I'm using `typename`, what is it that I'm doing wrong?

I'm using g++ 4.4.5 with the argument -std=c++0x, if it's relevant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want a typedef there (right now you're declaring an object named `iter`):

```
typedef typename std::list<T>::iterator iter;
```

Also, you need `typename` in the declaration of `binarySearch`:

```
 iter binarySearch(T toFind, typename std::list<T>::iterator min, typename std::list<T>::iterator max);
```

Of course, you can use `iter` at this point:

```
iter binarySearch(T toFind, iter min, iter max);
```

Comment: I'd just realized that I wasn't using typedef right. However, I'm still getting an error when I use typedef like that, as I'd put in the question.

Answer (score 2):

In the function

```
iter binarySearch(T toFind, std::list<T>::iterator min, std::list<T>::iterator max);
```

you specified private data member iter as the return type of the function.

This

```
typename std::list<T>::iterator iter;
```

is a definition of private data member `iter` that has type `typename std::list<T>::iterator`

If you mean a type name instead of the data member then you should to write either

```
typedef typename std::list<T>::iterator iter;
```

or

```
using iter =  typename std::list<T>::iterator;
```

Also it would be better to follow the genaral convetion used in the C++ Standard and name the type like

```
typedef typename std::list<T>::iterator iterator;
```

In this case the function declaration will look like

```
iterator binarySearch(T toFind, iterator min, iterator max);
```

Also it is better when iterators are preceed the value that is when the function is declared like

```
iterator binarySearch( iterator min, iterator max, T toFind );
```